# How to initialize field using lambda

Tags: java, design-patterns, lambda, initialization, java-8

I need an instance field of type ConnectionFactory.
A supplier can do it:

```
private Supplier<ConnectionFactory> connectionFactorySupplier = () -> {
    // code omitted
    return null;
};

private ConnectionFactory connectionFactory = connectionFactorySupplier.get();
```

It can be shortened to one line like so:

```
private ConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new Supplier<ConnectionFactory>() {
    @Override
    public ConnectionFactory get() {
        // code omitted
        return null;
    }
}.get();
```

Is there a way to make this a bit less verbose, using lambda? I've tried the following but it doesn't compile:

```
private ConnectionFactory connectionFactory= () -> {
    // code omitted
    return null;
}.get(); 
// Compilation failure
// error: lambda expression not expected here
```

Comment: Try calling the lambda not by using get() but by simply executing it with ().
Like this (you may have to add () around the lambda, I'm not sure):
private ConnectionFactory connectionFactory= () -> {
    // code omitted
    return null;
}();

Comment: @PsiX Can't compile that, please paste working code if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem in your last snippet is that there is no way for the compiler to guess that

```
() -> { 
// code omitted
    return null;
}
```

is a lambda expression that implements the SAM of the `Supplier` interface (and it seems you missed parentheses around the expression in the first place, but anyway).

The thing you could do is to cast the lambda in order to tell the compiler that this is actually the abstract method of the `Supplier` interface that you implement:

```
private ConnectionFactory connectionFactory = 
     ((Supplier<ConnectionFactory>)() -> {
         // code omitted
         return null;
     }).get();
```

But then what do you gain with that instead of having an initializer

```
private ConnectionFactory connectionFactory;
{
    //code omitted
    connectionFactory = null;
}
```

or initialize the connection within the constructor or with a final method:

```
private ConnectionFactory connectionFactory = initConnection();

private final ConnectionFactory initConnection() {
    //code omitted
    return null;
}
```

Comment: This is the answer I was looking for. It's still a bit verbose with the extra cast, but if you put that on the first line the whole expression (including the comment) becomes 4 lines, which I think is acceptable. Maybe with future java compilers the cast can be omitted.

Comment: @Lars Bohl: why do you bother about the type cast when the entire creation of a supplier is obsolete?

Comment: @Holger I want to do it in one expression. If you create an extra method, this is bad if you want to guarantee that there is only one instance. The initializer doesn't have that problem, but it may be far away from the declaration in a class with many fields, making it less readable.

Comment: You can write the initializer right after the field declaration.

Comment: OK thank, I didn't know that you can have more than one initializer. It's still  one extra line though, and the compiler will not check that you actually do the correct assignment in there.