# Java: using a lambda without assigning it to a variable

Tags: java, lambda

I'm using a lambda like so:

```
TwoValueCommand addition = (a, b) -> a + b;
return pushTwoValueCommand(addition);
```

Is there a way I can write it like this:

```
return pushTwoValueCommand(TwoValueCommand (a, b) -> a + b);
```

without having to create a variable?

**EDIT**

The answers to these questions:

[How to initialize field using lambda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33822363/how-to-initialize-field-using-lambda)

[Assign result of Java lambda to field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46045997/assign-result-of-java-lambda-to-field)

pointed me in the right direction, but they're phrased differently enough I want to post this anyway.

Comment: Do you run into a problem when you just write `return pushTwoValueCommand((a, b) -> a + b)`?

Comment: _pointed me in the right direction_ ... sorry, but then you are not asking a new question. You are basically saying, this is a duplicate question, a bit of different wording. It is ok for you to do still put up that different wording, but I still consider it ok, too, to close out as DUP then.

Comment: @GhostCat Fair enough, and I recognized the fact that it's a duplicate when I made the original post, _but_ the wording was different enough I felt like it would be useful to post. A google search was not pointing me in the right direction very quickly. I'm glad this question is linked to the other answers (which is why I posted them) but the word duplicate is pretty misleading. A note on duplicates: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54965111/java-unexpected-type-error-when-creating-a-stack-of-floats

Answer (score 5):

From [How to initialize field using lambda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33822363/how-to-initialize-field-using-lambda) I determined I could do this:

```
return pushTwoValueCommand((TwoValueCommand) (a, b) -> a + b); // put parentheses around type to cast lambda expression
```

From @ernest_k I see I can also do this:

```
return pushTwoValueCommand((a, b) -> a + b);
```

(though I don't understand how that version works—don't I have to use a functional interface?? https://medium.freecodecamp.org/learn-these-4-things-and-working-with-lambda-expressions-b0ab36e0fffc )

**EDIT**

@AndrewTobilko 's answer does a good job of explaining why you can do this (without the cast). The type can be inferred from pushTwoValueCommand's method definition, as long as pushTwoValueCommand wasn't overloaded (multiple definitions of pushTwoValueCommand) in such a way that the compiler can't determine which function interface to use.

Comment: If you let the method accept the actual type of functional interface (like I did in my answer), you'll be fine.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `(a, b) -> a + b` without context is ambiguous. It could be a `BinaryOperator<Integer>`, `BiFunction<Integer, Integer, Integer>`, `TwoValueCommand`. It could also represent any other functional interface that defined a method like `C method(A, B)`.

If you have `pushTwoValueCommand` overloaded with conflicting functional interfaces, you will run into the problem of ambiguity mentioned above.

If there is one version of `pushTwoValueCommand`, you can pass `(a, b) -> a + b` in directly and you'll be fine.

Comment: but, at @ernest_k 's suggestion, I tried it without the type cast and it still works—how?

Comment: because he assumed you were having an ambiguity issue (which could be a cause). In reality you just omit any interface specification when you're passing a lambda like these unless you absolutely _need_ to. as a result of what andrew was suggesting

Comment: @edmqkk no surprise. `(a, b) -> a + b` is a valid instance of the type you need to pass in the method

Comment: Wow, that's interesting—I would only need to specify the type if I had overloaded the pushTwoValueCommand method? That's surprising—it feels like everywhere else in Java you have to be so explicit, but you get a little bit of type inference in this one scenario? Weird—considering java doesn't even have an auto keyword or type inference from definitions.

Comment: @edmqkk actually, Java does a lot of type inference (whenever it's possible and wise). Often, we are just not aware of it and take it for granted.

Comment: @AndrewTobilko Cool. Thanks so much for answering!

Answer (score 1):

Another approach is enabling the `pushTwoValueCommand` method to accept a *functional interface*.
For this specific usecase, a `BiFunction` ([documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/BiFunction.html)) is ideal. Your code could be rewritten as

```
<T> T pushTwoValueCommand(
        final BiFunction<T, T, T> function,
        final T right,
        final T left) {
    // Do something else, and then
    return function.apply(right, left);
}
```

and used as

```
return pushTwoValueCommand((a, b) -> a + b, 1, 3);
```

Comment: interesting. I'll have to come back to this after I've spent some more time with Java. Thanks!

Comment: @edmqkk using this approach, the compiler will also stop you from using incompatible data types, as you're using a "T" type everywhere.